# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' [Django]

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-models, valueerror

I'm working on a Django application which fetches JSON data from an API and stores it in PostgreSQL database.
But while migrating the app I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What should I change in code to resolve this error?
Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 415, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 155, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 229, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How to fix this problem?

Here's my code for models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Projects(models.Model):
        data = JSONField(null=False)
        project_id=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        project_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        status=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        country=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        locations=JSONField()
        mjtheme=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        project_docs=JSONField()
        source=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        mjtheme_namecode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        docty=models.TextField()
        countryname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        countrycode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        themecode=models.IntegerField()
        theme_namecode=models.IntegerField()
        project_url=models.TextField()
        totalcommamt=models.IntegerField()
        mjthemecode=models.IntegerField()
        sector1=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme1=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme2=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        theme3=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        projectinfo=models.TextField()
        country_namecode=models.CharField(max_length=5)
        p2a_updated_date=models.IntegerField()
        p2a_flag=models.CharField(max_length=5)
        project_abstract=JSONField()
```

And here's the code for fetch.py file which is stored under /management/commands/fetch.py:

```
import requests
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from worldBank.worldBankApp.models import Projects

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        response = requests.get("https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&countryshortname_exact=India&source=IBRD&kw=N&rows=7")
        data = response.json()
        projects = data['projects']

        #print(data)

        for project in projects:
            print(projects[project])
            print("\n\n")

            data = projects[project]

            Projects.objects.create(

                project_id = data['id'],
                project_name = data['project_name'],
                status = data['status'],
                country = data['countryshortname'],
                locations = data['locations'],
                mjtheme = data['mjtheme'],
                project_docs = data['projectdocs'],
                source = data['source'],
                mjtheme_namecode = data['mjtheme_namecode'],
                docty = data['docty'],
                countryname = data['countryname'],
                countrycode = data['countrycode'],
                themecode = data['themecode'],
                theme_namecode = data['theme_namecode'],
                project_url = data['url'],
                totalcommamt = data['totalcommamt'],
                mjthemecode = data['mjthemecode'],
                sector1 = data['sector1'],
                theme1 = data['theme1'],
                theme2 = data['theme2'],
                theme3 = data['theme3'],
                projectinfo = data['projectinfo'],
                country_namecode = ['country_namecode'],
                p2a_updated_date = data['p2a_updated_date'],
                p2a_flag = data['p2a_flag'],
                project_abstract = data['project_abstract']

                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is coming for any of the following `IntegerField` .

```
themecode=models.IntegerField()
theme_namecode=models.IntegerField()
totalcommamt=models.IntegerField()
mjthemecode=models.IntegerField()
p2a_updated_date=models.IntegerField()
```

reason: you supposed to assign integer value(e.g. 4 or '4') instead its not. Please check the value of above fields.

===== EDIT

value coming in response for integer field(s):

```
themecode: "79,77,66", # invalid
mjthemecode: "10,10,5", # invalid
p2a_updated_date: "2017-09-01 00:00:00.0", # invalid
theme_namecode: [] # invalid
```

==== EDIT: Place following code after `data = projects[project]`

```
for k, v in data.items():
    try:
        int(v)
    except ValueError:
        print k, v
        break
```

Comment: should I include IntegerField(max_length=100)??but doesn't solved the problem either

Comment: No. problem is when you assign value like ` p2a_updated_date= data['p2a_updated_date']`. Here data['p2a_updated_date'] should be integer.

Comment: tried assigning IntegerField('100') but same problem

Comment: ok  let me try 'p2a_updated_date= int(data['p2a_updated_date'])'

Comment: so which field is suitable for these values? @navyad please help

Comment: I even commented these 5 lines which use these fields but still same problem

Comment: updated my answer.  `print k, v` will tell you the culprit.

Comment: Nice way to find the error with try and except, if anyone else is looking at this, if you have more fields different from IntegerField just exclude them like this:         for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items():
            if k not in ['different_type_field_name']:
                try:
                    int(v)
                except ValueError:
                    print(k, v)
            else:
                print(k, v)

Answer (score 0):

Navyad is largely correct, you are trying to assign strings to integer fields (`themecode` is a good example).

Looking through the JSON, I'm seeing things like `"themecode": "79,77,66"`. This simply *cannot* be inserted into an integer field. You need to change those to `models.CharField` or somehow pre-process the data (extract the first number, for example).

Comment: I changed all the IntegerField() to CharField(max_length=100) but still same  error :ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: even tried changing all the IntegerField() to CharField() but getting same error